# Is there anything like SQLs Decimal in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, decimal

There is great data type in MySQL Decimal, which is good to store prices like:

```
CREATE TABLE books( title VARCHAR(100), author VARCHAR(100), price DECIMAL(6,2));
```

So how can I create similar schema in MongoDB?
I can not find anything like `DECIMAL` there.
My code in node.js+mongoose looks like this so far:

```
const booksSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    price: Number
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is data type called Decimal128, introduced in v3.4. So the database supports it.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

<strike>But node.js/mongoose probably doesn't, given that all numbers in javascript are floats.</strike> see Stennie's comment below.

Comment: The MongoDB Node.js driver has a [Decimal128 class](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Decimal128.html) and Mongoose  4.8.0+ also has schema support for the  decimal type. As at the Node 3.1 driver there isn't any support for client-side decimal arithmetic so you will either have to convert to a different representation or perform calculations on the MongoDB server. Helpful blog post from the current Mongoose maintainer: [A Node.js Perspective on MongoDB 3.4: Decimal Type](http://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-34-decimal.html).